# Connecting arduino with MATLAB

Tags: arduino-nano, matlab

I installed Octave support package for Arduino and it is listed in the packages installed when pkg list command is run.But when the command  "a= arduino('COM8')";
is run,"error: serial: Error opening the interface: No such file or directory" is shown.Please respond.

Comment: Are you able to connect with the Arduino on COM8 through the Arduino IDE?

Comment: So in the Windows device manager, what COM ports do you see?

Answer (score 2):

Using `clear` command on Octave before executing `a=arduino('COM8')` will remove this problem.

Use it like this:

```
clear
a=arduino('COM8')
```